# Generating a coruppted PDF file from a visual force page

Tags: triggers, salesforce, pdf-generation, apex, visualforce

I am trying to generate a PDF file attachment in an after update trigger and below is the trigger handler method but the file sent is corrupted.

```
public static void sendEOB(List<Claim_Payment__c> newList,Map<Id, Claim_Payment__c> oldMap){
        for(Claim_Payment__c claimPayment : newList){
            if (claimPayment.Status__c == 'Pending'){
                String sfUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
                String myURL = 'https://'+sfUrl+'/apex/ClaimPayments?Id='+ claimPayment.Id;
                PageReference pdf = new PageReference(myURL);
                
                // the contents of the report in pdf form
                Blob body;
                
                try {
                    body = pdf.getContent();
                } catch (VisualforceException e) {
                    body = Blob.valueOf('PDF Get Failed');
                }
                
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
                attach.setFileName('Payment_Statement.pdf');
                attach.setInline(false);
                attach.Body = body;
                
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setUseSignature(false);
                mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {'whatever@gmail.com' });
                mail.setSubject('Payment Statement');
                mail.setHtmlBody('Important Statement Attachment!');
                mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach }); 
                
                // Send the email
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update** :

Using @future(callout=true) & getContentAsPDF() now i get this error message **FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error** on executing   `body = pdf.getContent();`

```
public static void sendEOB(List<Claim_Payment__c> newList,Map<Id, Claim_Payment__c> oldMap){
        for(Claim_Payment__c claimPayment : newList){
            if (claimPayment.Status__c == 'Pending'){
                String sfUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
                String myURL = 'https://'+sfUrl+'/apex/ClaimPayments?Id='+ claimPayment.Id;
                
                sendPDFEmail.sendPDF(myURL);
            }
        } 
    }
```

```
Public class sendPDFEmail{
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void sendPDF(String myURL){
        PageReference pdf = new PageReference(myURL);
        
        // the contents of the report in pdf form
        Blob body;
        body = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
        
       // Rest of the implementation goes below
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What errors (if any) you see in debug log? From what I remember you might need `@future(callout=true)` or other asynchronous processing (Queueable etc) because [calling getContent counts as callout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm). And shouldn't that be `getContentAsPdf`? or is the page already set to renderas="pdf"?

If you download the file - what size it is, couple bytes or bigger? That try-catch is swallowing the actual error message, you don't even show it as `System.debug(e);` Remove the try-catch and check in the debbug what exactly it explodes on.

Comment: using `@future(callout=true)` , `getContentAsPdf` and removing the try-catch now i get this log error **FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error** when executing this line `body = pdf.getContentAsPDF();` which is an error i can not identify. @eyescream

Comment: 1. Are you sure your Profile/Permission sets have access to that VF page. 2. Does your profile have login hours active, see https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BMLNQA4. 3. Can you try constructing the url differently (and with lowercase "id"!): `PageReference pdf = Page.ClaimPayments; pdf.getParameters().put('id', claimPayment.Id); Blob b = pdf.getContentAsPDF(); System.debug(b);`

Comment: Thank You a lot, your tips got it actually to work this time. @eyescream